# Editing a modern SharePoint page built with html-hard code

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, css, html, edit

I have a SharePoint site that I need to make a few minor changes on.  The problem is that this page was built with html/hard-coded, so it won't allow me to simply click "Edit page", then do what I need to do.  A colleague of mine used SP Designer to make edits to the page previously, but when I downloaded SP Designer 2013, it won't let me open an SP page (says account is in a bad state).

My question is: Is there an alternative to editing this SP page with Designer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch! Account in a bad state is quite trivial to fix. But try this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/error-opening-site-in-sharepoint-designer-your/d00f4aae-74d8-46a7-b9d1-565dfcaadf48

Another way is to:

1. open up any Document Library with Windows Explorer,
2. then try navigating to the folder containing the HTML file.
3. download the HTML file.
4. edit as you wish, then re-upload back.

It's really painful, but it does the job.